# Group by column & row in one part of expression, group by column only in another part of expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to find a way to use the `Group By` functionality to create a table where the numerator of a fraction is grouped both by column and row, and the denominator is grouped only by column.

Here's my existing expression:

```
=Round(Sum(Fields!Days_In_Step.Value)/CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value),1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

When grouped by rows (groupName) and columns (month/year) the numerator (`Sum(Fields!Days_In_Step.Value)`) gives me good data, but the denominator (`CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value)`) is also grouped by row (groupName) and I don't want that.

I have a SQL solution but am trying to do this entire within SSRS expressions, if possible.

**edit**
Sample Data:

[image]

It would look like this.  The background is that these groupings are counts of days and the "all" are counts of tickets, so we are trying to see who is sitting on their tickets longer.

Here is a mock-up including a sample data set using a pivot table:

[image]

**Edit 2**

Here is a full sample data set:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rYPMcrLNB-FZN64Fn2-y3FtnM2iQo2VMH7YTdfiVnKM/edit?usp=sharing

I need to group on month as well as year, and I do not want to see "Exclude" in the group rows, however they cannot be filtered out of the tablix without being removed from the overall population, which is required for the denominator.

Comment: Share sample data and expected results in order to help you.

Comment: How is being `ALL` row calculated? I see it is a distinct count of IDs but in which scope? It would be better if you share the raw dataset without gropings for replicating your scenario.

Comment: that would be nice, yes.  Scrubbing would take time.  `All` are the number of tickets, those tickets can go into ownership of the 3 different groups at any time.  So, `All` is count of tickets by month, while the `Groups` are SUMs of ticket days by month and by group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the scoping of aggregate functions. When you use aggregate function they run under the scope where it is placed in the tablix by default. In your case `Sum()` and `CountDistinct()` functions are running in both row groups (Owner Group) and column group (Month Group).

Fortunately, you can specify the scope that you want your aggregate function computes the aggregation, simply add the group name in the function:

```
CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value,"MonthGroup")
```

The whole expression is like this:

```
=Round(Sum(Fields!Days_In_Step.Value)/
CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value, "MonthGroup"),1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

> Replace `"MonthGroup"` by the actual name of your group in columns
>   group.

This is result using the sample data you provided:

[image]

I've used this expression to show you how it is produced:

```
=Sum(Fields!Days.Value) & "/" 
& CountDistinct(Fields!Ticket.Value,"MonthGroup") & "=" &
Sum(Fields!Days.Value)/CountDistinct(Fields!Ticket.Value,"MonthGroup")
```

> Note my column group is named `MonthGroup`.

---

**UPDATE:** Scoping multiple groups in CountDistinct function.

Firstly I am not filtering the dataset, I prefer hide the `Exclude` rows using the below expression in the `Hidden` property of the `Row Visibility` window:

```
=IIF(Fields!Group.Value="Exclude" OR Fields!Group.Value="-1",true,false)
```

[image]

To count distinct id grouping by Month and Year but not by Group you can create a child group below Month group as you can see below:

[image]

My group is called `Group2` and I used this expression in the `Group on` textbox.

[image]

```
=Fields!End_Month.Value & "-" & Fields!End_Year.Value
```

It will create a group per every `Month-Year` combination. When you create the group it will be added as a column group so you will have to delete the row so you will be prompted if you want to delete the group and row or delete the row only. Delete only the row leaving the group.

Now the expression you have to use is

```
=Round(Sum(Fields!Days.Value)/CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value, "Group2"),1,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

> Replace `Group2` by the name of the created group in your case.

This is the whole recreation of your scenario:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is helpful, but leads to a wrinkle that I did not previously disclose: That I am filtering out groups that are categorized as "Excluded".  This ends up excluding from the dataset and not just the resultant tablix.  Is there a way for me to hide a group in the tablix without filtering the data?

Comment: Another problem I have is with being constrained to a single grouping.  I used "month" only in my example for simplicity, but ideally I would want to use month and year, but the expression constrains to a single group.  Not ideal, ultimately.

Comment: Edit your questions and include those details, I think you can achieve what you described but you have to provide full data sample and details of your conditions and expected results.

Comment: I'm going ahead and marking this as the answer.  It's getting too convoluted to be viable, I think doing it on the SQL side is much more clear.

Comment: @n8. Check my edition, I suggest you generate the required aggregations in T-SQL, however this is a SSRS solution to your problem you can use.